# R: Yahoo/Bing or other alternatives to Google Earth for geocoding?

Tags: r, dictionary, gps, gis

I am estimating latitudes and longitudes for 500K+ locations. The `geocode()` function in the `dismo` package appears to be perfect, but uses Google Earth as the backend. The problem is that GE has a usage limit of 2500 queries/day only, which throws `dismo` out for me as a realistic solution. So my questions are:

1. Is there any other package which does the same thing, but uses Yahoo, Bing or some another backend with more generous limits?
2. Is there any other way of running bulk queries outside of R which I may not be aware of? The solution must necessarily be free :-(

NOTE: I am running the queries for places in India, so a US-only solution will not do.

SUPPLEMENTARY QUESTION: I am not a developer, so I might be talking through a hat here. It seems to me that the `geocode()` function is calling Google's API under the hood, and is hence able to spit out the lat/long coordinates. Since `r/dismo` is open-source, is there any way to change the pointer to Yahoo/Bing?

Comment: [This question of mine has some answers](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6/geocoding-thats-anonymous-good-and-free-does-it-exist/14#14) - my context was a little different, but you might find something useful there.

Comment: What is the geographic extent of the locations? Worldwide will likely need to be an online geocoder, but smaller areas will have potential offline solutions.

Comment: All in India. My queries will have to run on the names of villages, subdistricts, districts and states. I have tested google's API for a week and have feeling the lat/longs are quite in the ballpark.

Comment: What exactly to you want to do? Maybe you can use OpenStreetMap to find your coordinates. It should work in most bigger cities...

Answer (score 3):

Yahoo will allow up to 50k queries per API key per day. Bing will allow 10k. Google's limit of 2500 is based on IP address, rather than an API key. All of these have pretty strict terms of use around how the data may be used. Generally, they insist that it only be used in a display (e.g., a webpage) and may not be stored in any way. The docs are worth a read if you intend to use the services for anything other than exploratory research.

You might try the [geocoding service at USC](https://webgis.usc.edu/Services/Geocode/Default.aspx). I haven't used it myself, but it appears to allow up to 2500 requests per transaction and has both a batch service via file upload and an API.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative (that I haven't tried) would be to use [Pete Warden's Data Science Toolkit](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/) via [Ryan Elmore's RDSTK package](https://github.com/rtelmore/RDSTK).  It's unclear what the limit on Pete Warden's API is, but the whole thing is open source and he provides instructions on how to set up your own instance.  In that case, you'd have to tweak the RDSTK package to point to your own instance, but that's a pretty trivial search-and-replace in [this file](https://github.com/rtelmore/RDSTK/blob/master/src/RDSTK/R/functions.R).

Major caveat: I haven't actually tried this.  My geocoding scheme got sidetracked, so I haven't been able to follow up on these things yet.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. But a random search reveals too many inconsistencies/holes. Good call, though.

Comment: Matt... Your comment gave me an idea which I've put in as a supplementary question in my original post. Sorry I'm clueless about changing packages myself.

Comment: @user702432 Sorry to hear that DSTK didn't work out for you.  I took a look at the dismo::geocode function, and I don't think you could easily modify it to point to another API - most of the code in there looks pretty specific to Google.  You might have better luck outside of R - maybe take a look at [geopy](http://code.google.com/p/geopy/), which lets you choose from a few different services (I haven't used it myself).

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I guess I'll have to delve into Python now. I'm afraid I know only the rudimentary stuff.

Comment: @user702432 You can always try asking at http://gis.stackexchange.com/ too - just make sure to link back to this question.  Good luck!